# How to change yii2-usuario registration module to allow admin to register users

Tags: yii2, yii2-user, yii2-extension

I have the following use case for my system:
Registration:

- Admin registers a new user i.e. email, username and submits.
- Email is send to the user to confirm with new password.
- user confirms email, changes password and goes ahead to update
  profile.

I have installed and configured yii2-usuario module by 2amigos. How can I achieve the above with this module?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [documentation](http://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Do you have an admin permission/user configured yet?

Comment: [**`THIS`**](http://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is where you start not on stackoverflow.